# Replacing the Decorator design pattern with a list of methods

Tags: design-patterns, decorator

So I've been going over some design patterns and I came across this discussion
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43565475/using-lists-instead-of-decorator-pattern

I've been thinking that in all honesty I can always replace a decorator design pattern with an ArrayList of methods that I can activate in the order of insertion. Maybe a plus side is that I can dynamically remove intermediate functionalities that were added this way while in a normal decorator pattern that would be difficult to do.

So what kind of real advantage does a Decorator pattern have over a list of methods?
Can anyone think of examples or reasons why a list of methods called in succession would be inherently worse?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read **all** the linked question' answers? Because there's a lot of information, insights and pros and cons there. Runtime flexibility (lists) vs readability and expressiveness (decorator)

Comment: If you're not in control of the interface where you need to plug in the decorated object, then you *have* to use a decorator (cause the interface doesn't accept a list). Also, doing both pre-effects and post-effects with a list is a bit awkward. That said, structurally, a stack of decorators is essentially a linked list. And, you might want to simultaneously decorate more than one method.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović I actually really like the example with decorating multiple methods at once. In general it is still possible with multiple lists (one list per decorated method) but maintaining a 2D array instead of using the decorator pattern sounds like a nightmare to maintain

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of the decorator pattern with inheritance is you can use it with any class without access to the internals and pass that decorator object into others transparently.

So I'm using some library with an Auth class with Auth.IsAllowed() and I want to fiddle with the logic a bit I can decorate and pass the decorated object into the rest of the library functions no problem.

If you know you will need multiple 'decorators' then there is probably a better solution than either version of the decorator pattern.

The coffee example is insane no one would program that. OOP examples always have Cats and Dogs of type Animal etc but in real life you are overriding `EndStream()` or `Crypography.KeySize()` where the inheritance ideas like 'A is a B' don't hold the same meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Both are implementations of decorator pattern. The chained decorators implementation or onion style implementation offers [loose coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling).

Consider the following aggregated decorators:

- `BDecorator`, which decorates `ADecorator` which decorates `SomethingToDecorate`
- `CDecorator`, which decorates `BDecorator` which decorates `ADecorator` which decorates `SomethingToDecorate`

In the scenario where `CDecorator` decorates a list containing `BDecorator` and `ADecorator`, `CDecorator` has to communicate to `BDecorator` to exclude what uses from `ADecorator`.

In the scenario where `CDecorator` decorates a list containing only `BDecorator` the list is redundant. `CDecorator` could get the instance of `BDecorator` without being wrapped in a list.